# C++ - MATLAB : updating a Sparse Matrix blockwise

Tags: c++, matlab, sparse-matrix, eigen

Matlab code here

```
 N = 4096;
 x       =   linspace(-1,1,N);     
 A = sparse(100000,100000); 
 index = 1:32;

 A(index,index)    =   kernel(x(index),x(index));
  //kernel here outputs a 32 x 32 matrix
```

I have to convert the MATLAB code to C++,but I am stuck at **sparse** function, I tried using:

```
 N=4096;
 Eigen::VectorXd x = Eigen::VectorXd::LinSpaced(N,-1,1); 
 Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> A(Asize,Asize);
 A.block(1,1,index.size(), index.size()) = Kernel();
```

But SparseMatrix has **block** as read only function and therefore can't be useful for updating the matrix.

**Another Point:**

I have gone through the Eigen documentation and checked a different form of SparseMatrix declaration :

```
 typedef Eigen::Triplet<double> T;
 std::vector<T>tripleList;
 tripleList.reserve(nnz);

 for(...)
 {
  // ...
  tripletList.push_back(T(i,j,v_ij));   //?? what are these values?
  }
 A.setFromTriplets(tripleList.begin(), tripleList.end());
```

But I don't understand what should be value of nnz, should it be the value that I get from Matlab code and what value should I push through the for loop? Will they be random, how do I select the "pushed values" given that matrix size is so large.

Also, the last question remains, how will the sparse matrix after declaration gets updated block-wise?

Comment: `nnz` means "number of non zeroes". I assume that is for memory allocation in Eigen. Additionally, ` A(index,index)    =   kernel(x(index),x(index));` this can be done with a simple double nested loop in C++, you dont need a one-liner

Comment: According to the [documentaion](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialSparse.html) for performance reasons, writing to a sub-sparse-matrix is  limited. and only you can update contiguous sets of columns. with the size of submatrix should be known at compile time

Comment: @AnderBiguri    How can it be done in a double nested loop? are u suggesting using the function "insert"? but then if the same line is repeated multiple times I have to first store the result from Kernel() every time and then insert it in sparse matrix.

Answer (score 3):

In general, Eigen sparse matrix blocks are const. The exception to this rule is e.g. `m.col(i)` in a column major matrix or `.row(i)` in a row major one.

As for your second point, `nnz` is the number of non-zeros. By specifying how many non-zeros the matrix needs to hold at the beginning, you minimize the number of reallocations/copies needed when constructing the sparse matrix. See the [documentation](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SparseMatrix.html#a1518e58ac49bed0e2385b722a034f7d3). Also, note that [other overload](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SparseMatrix.html#ac2b219eb36fbab0bfae535cfbfc74a76) is useful if you know how many elements are needed in each column.
Regarding the for loop, assume you had three arrays: `columnIndices`, `rowIndices` and `values`, all of length `nnz`. Your for loop would look like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < nnz; i++)
{
    tripletList.push_back(T(columnIndices[i], rowIndices[i], values[i]));
}
```

Alternatively, you could compute the values for each triplet within the for loop.

Comment: Does this method works when the values are zeroes? Because I went through documentation , it said : "fill with nonzero elements". what if I want to update an already exiisting sparse matrix to some small matrix conating zeroes?